# What Scala version is used in maven Scala plugin by default?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-scala-plugin

[Here](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/plugin-info.html) link to maven Scala plugin usage. But it is not mentioned what exactly Scala version it uses. I have created maven Scala project with following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then I build effective pom, the plugin section for maven Scala plugin is:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>compile</goal>
           <goal>testCompile</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

And also no Scala version in configuration tag. So what Scala version does maven Scala plugin use by default?

Comment: run the `mvn scala:console` goal and check the version http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_console.html

Comment: It works! Why you did not post your comment as answer? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

run the `mvn scala:console` goal and check the [version](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_console.html)